# Google Drive file delete error. The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth, google-workspace, google-drive-shared-drive

I am working on google drive api. I have a requirement to delete files which are uploaded by some other users. We are using common folder to upload files. I need to download and delete files from uploaded location.

Code.

```
    do{
       FileList result2 = service.files().list().setFields("nextPageToken, files(id, name,parents,mimeType,owners)").setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
       for (File file : listFiles) {
           downloadFile(file)//This method download files. ITs working file
           service.files().delete(file.getId()).execute();
           pageToken = result2.getNextPageToken();
       }
    }while (pageToken != null);

service.files().delete(file.getId()).execute();
throwing exception
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 403 Forbidden
{
  "code" : 403,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.",
    "reason" : "insufficientFilePermissions"
  } ],
  "message" : "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
}
```

I know I am not the owner so I can't delete files. Is there a way to update my role or create super user role and delete files from drive.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

> The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.

Means exactly that the user does not have permission to delete the file.  There is really nothing you can do about that other than contact the owner of the file and have them delete it.

I dont know how you are uploading these files to this central location but an idea would be use a service account to upload the files.  Then it will own the files.  Then when you want to delete them you can have the service account user do the delete the file rather than relying upon the user who is currently logged in to delete the file.

Comment: Service account also does not have rights to transfer ownership even when it is the owner.

Comment: If the service account is the owner of the file it can grant others access to the file and it can also transfer ownership a service account is just a user like anyother user

Comment: @DalmTo It works for google apps files and does not work for files you uploaded through service account. I uploaded wav file and failed transfer ownership https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62699404/how-to-update-permissions-in-google-drive-api-v3

Comment: The service account can defiantly transfer file ownership I had an application that did this years ago.

Answer (score 2):

> I know I am not the owner so I can't delete files

You are absolutely correct on that. Deleting and trashing of files can only be done by the owner.

There is one workaround though. You can remove the parent ID from the file. This will remove the file from the folder. To do this, use the `removeParents` parameter of the [Files: Update endpoint](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/update). This is also what Google Drive does when you "delete" a file (that you don't own) from a shared folder via the web interface.

One caveat of this method is that the file size will still count towards the owning user's Google Drive storage limit.

Comment: What if I'm the owner of the file and I get the same error trying transfer ownership to another account?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, maybe your service's scopes not enough to delete file/folder.

If you use Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE_METADATA, remove it. Then use Google_Service_Drive::DRIVE scope.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this scenario: User A shares Folder X with User B. User A remains the owner of Folder X while User B is an editor

It appears that any file uploaded to Folder X by User B will be owned by User B, and User A will be granted Editor permissions.

Within the Web UI - User A can "Delete" the file; but this appears to not actually be the case. The file will still exist, but I believe what's happening is that Google is just removing the active user from the share permissions. Essentially, if you went into the share dialog and removed yourself - it'd be the same thing. Again, an assumption here.

@Finn's answer did not work for me. I believe the "Parent" is the folder - not the owner. The file I experimented with only had one parent, and it seems to match up with the folder ID that I see in my URL when looking. Removing it didn't remove it, however it didn't throw an error.

What I did have success with was the [Permissions.delete](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/reference/rest/v3/permissions/delete) method and removing my own permission. After refreshing the Web UI, the file immediately disappeared - and when I sent the link to User B, they said the file still existed - and was even in the original folder.

When using the Permissions.delete method, Google appears to expect a JSON payload where the query parameters are specified there, not as URL parameters.

One issue I see with this though is ensuring that company data is kept on company accounts. If a folder is shared with someone's personal email then they will always own those files and it's impossible for the company to take ownership and remove them.