# How to update permissions in Google Drive API v3?

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api, google-apps

I uploaded wav file using service account, service account created the file, service account is the owner:

```
metadata = {'name': filename, 'parents': [FolderId]}
media = MediaFileUpload(filepath, mimetype='audio/wav')
r = drive.files().create(body=metadata, media_body=media, fields='id').execute()

{'permissions': [{'deleted': False,
              'displayName': 'My name',
              'emailAddress': 'myemail@gmail.com',
              'id': '00654354190098938408',
              'kind': 'drive#permission',
              'photoLink': 'https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/photo.jpg',
              'role': 'writer',
              'type': 'user'},
             {'deleted': False,
              'displayName': 'myservice@myservice.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
              'emailAddress': 'myservice@myservice.iam.gserviceaccount.com',
              'id': '16815597635264162472',
              'kind': 'drive#permission',
              'role': 'owner',
              'type': 'user'}]}
```

Then I'm trying to change the `role` of `myemail` account from `writer` to `owner` and get an error:

```
drive.permissions().update(fileId=fileId, permissionId='00654354190098938408', transferOwnership=True,
    body={'role': 'owner'}).execute()
```

> The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.

What is wrong?

My service account is the owner, I CAN delete the file through the service account and it does not have permissions to transfer ownership, why?
When I create a spreadsheet with `service` account and transfer ownership to `myemail` account it works perfectly.

I tried to create new permission and got this:

```
permission = {
    "emailAddress": 'myemail@gmail.com',
    "role": 'owner',
    "type": 'user',
}
drive.permissions().create(fileId=fileId, body=permission, transferOwnership=True).execute()
```

> "Bad Request. User message: "You can't yet change the owner of this item. (We're working on it.)""

Comment: I thought that this situation might be the same with [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60009697). In this thread, the method of Permissions: create couldn't be used with the batch request at that time. In this case, the error like `currently under development` occurred. But recently, this got to be able to be used. So I believe that your current issue like `We're working on it.` will be resolved in the future update.

Comment: Can you share how are you uploading the file? Also have you tried using [Permissions: update](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/update) with `transferOwnership`?

Comment: @Tanaike They have been working [on it for the last 8 years](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14402569/change-acl-of-pdf-and-non-google-documents-edu-domain). Instead, is there a way to set different user as the owner inside `drive.files().create(...)` method?

Comment: @Kessy I added uploading to the post. I already used `update`, please read my post.

Comment: Any chance you want to try and upload say a doc file and transfer that?  I dont think you can transfer wav files.

Comment: @DaImTo I can transfer ownership for Google Docs, Google Sheets, Google Slides, Google Forms, Google Drawings, Google My Maps, Folders. They are all google format files. But it does not work for any uploaded file which is not in google format. A workaround I can imagine is to add another user as an owner to `drive.files().create(...)`. But I don't know is it possible or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the documentation found here [Make someone else the owner of your file](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2494892)

> From your personal account, you can transfer the following file types:
>
> - Google Docs
> - Google Sheets
> - Google Slides
> - Google Forms
> - Google Drawings
> - Google My Maps
> - Folders
>   Tip: When you transfer ownership of a folder it transfers only the selected folder and does not include the files inside.

If google drive doesn't support transferring that file type then the service account isnt going to be able to transfer it either.

Workaround.  Have the user upload the file to their account and not the service account.

Comment: I have uploaded txt files using x@gmail.com user and trying to transfer the owner to y@gmail and I get error "You can't yet change the owner of this item". Only works for doc files. Google's try api section on documentation has the same behavior for non .doc/.docx files. Works via google drive native UI